# How to determine the count of distinct values in a Django model's field?

Tags: python, django, distinct

Suppose I have the following model:

```
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    '''
    Represents information about a user
    '''

    # ...

    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

If I wish to determine each of the distinct ages present in the table, I can do this:

```
Profile.objects.distinct('age')
```

However, this doesn't include any information on the *number* of rows that contain each distinct age. Is there any way to obtain this information without resorting to raw SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Profile.objects.values('age').annotate(Count('age'))

Result: [{'age': 10, 'age__count': 52}, ...]
```